# where are bios logs stored and do they affect performance in any way?

Tags: windows, bios, performance

now for some weird reasons I can't delete bios logs and I have insane ocd when it comes to performance, I have a lot of logs like 50, where are they stored? and do they affect windows performance? + can bios get corrupted for spamming f12 the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BIOS logs are stored in CMOS with the BIOS's settings. Most BIOSs allow you to clear the logs, but will add an entry that the log was cleared. If you are having an issue clearing the log, you might check if there is a BIOS update. Applying it might fix that issue. There is no manual method of clearing the logs.

As for performance, the logs have zero affect on the performance of any operating system. The only part of the BIOS that matters are the settings.

Comment: thanks =) is it fine if I get thousands of these logs? is there even a reason to clear them?

Comment: @xxocdretardxx you won't. Depending on the BIOS it will start overwriting them. Worst case flash the BIOS to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks again :D:D have a great day